# Any way to check an object if its breeze entity object?

Tags: breeze

Any way to check an object if its breeze entity object ?Simply check could be the considering the existence of "entityAspect" prop of obj but i wonder if there is more elegant way of doing that such instanceof ,typeof or else.

```
 function (obj){//Evaluate the obj is breeze entity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually checking for the 'entityAspect' property is the right way to go. Remember that breeze can make use of your own custom entity constructors, that have no breeze semantics at all. In these cases, Breeze either wraps or augments your custom entities constructors ( depending on the modelLibrary registered with breeze), so there is no real way other than by checking for the augmentation to determine if the entity is really a breeze entity.